# Reading stdin from python program started via ssh in terminal

Tags: ssh, bash, python

I have got this little python3 script `test.py`:

```
import sys

print('test1')
test1 = sys.stdin.read()
print('test2')
test2 = sys.stdin.read()

print(test1)
print(test2)
```

And I would like to run this script remotely via ssh like this:

`ssh srvid 'cd; python3 test.py'`

I would expect that program prints `test1`, then will wait for input, and then prints `test2` and again wait for input.

But the behaviour is slightly different:

```
ssh srvid 'cd; python3 test.py'
hell
test1
test2
hell
```

The program first waited for input. I have entered `hell` and pressed enter and then ctr+d for eof. Script did not wait for second input, and printed out `test1` and `test2`.

It seems, that stdin / stdout are somehow blocked.

I tried same example in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello world";
read test;
echo "helloworld 2";
read test2;
echo $test;
echo $test2;
```

When I invoked this script via ssh, everything worked as I am expecting.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you do the same thing with `ssh -t host 'command'`?

Comment: Wow, no... when I use -t switch everything works. Thank you very much!! You can add the answer for acception :-)

Comment: When you specify a command for ssh to execute it assumes the command is noninteractive and doesn't allocate a pseudoterminal. The `-t` forces pty allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a [libc convention](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Buffering-Concepts.html) for stdio buffering. If stdout is a tty, it is typically line-buffered; fully buffered otherwise.

As others have suggested, passing the -t flag to ssh forces psuedo-tty allocation, and you get line-buffering as a result.

However, you could also explicitly flush stdout to get a similar result, as in:

```
import sys

print('test1')
sys.stdout.flush()
test1 = sys.stdin.readline() # ctrl+d and .read() effectively closes 
print('test2')               # stdin for the duration
sys.stdout.flush()
test2 = sys.stdin.readline()

print(test1)
print(test2)
# flushing happens implicitly when the stream is closed
```

Another option, would be to run python in totally unbuffered mode with the `-u` flag, as in

```
ssh srvid 'cd; python3 -u test.py'
```

Additional workarounds can be found in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering).

---

> The program first waited for input. I have entered `hell` and pressed
>   enter and then ctr+d for eof. Script did not wait for second input,
>   and printed out `test1` and `test2`.

I'm pretty sure the script didn't stop at the second input because you sent it an EOF during the first.

---

FWIW, I would probably write the python this way, unless you need multi-line input. It's a closer comparison to your bash example, IMO.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('test1')
test1 = input() # raw_input() in python 2.x
print('test2')         
test2 = input()

print(test1)
print(test2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. I was thinking about flushing for a while, but I did not give it a try.  Btw, I needed multi-line input :-)